# How to revert the list order back to how it was before the last change if the AJAX request fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sorting, sortablejs

I'm using the [Sortable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable) JS library with jQuery to execute an AJAX request when the list order changes. I'm doing it this way:

```
<ul id="items">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('items');

    Sortable.create(el, {
      onEnd: function (event) {
        var new_position = event.newIndex+1;

        $.ajax({
          type: 'PATCH',
          url: 'path/to',
          data: {'new_position': new_position},
          dataType: 'script'
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Revert the list order to how it was before the current sort started.
          });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I would like to revert the list order back to how it was before the last change if the AJAX request fails.

How can I make that?

Comment: Perhaps `onSort: function (e) {
  var clone = $("#items").clone(true);  
 }` and then replace and re-issue the sortable.create on the replaced ul

Answer (score 0):

You can clone list node with vanilla JS `cloneNode` or jQuery `clone` method and sort cloned node. Then, on success you can swap original node with cloned one. Or you can make it the other way - get the node, clone it, sort the original one, and swap it with cloned one on fail, however I would go with the first approach (swap on success) since you limit the number of eventual DOM changes.
References:

- https://api.jquery.com/clone/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use cloning functions within the Sortable library?

Comment: I got a little confused about the success callback solution (sorry about that, thought about some different library) but here is a ready solution with Sortable and "fail" callback:
https://jsfiddle.net/sLf1u0dn/1/